# IBM AS400 ISeries Partitions

Tags: ibm, partition, ibm-midrange

Can I have in one IBM ISeries partitions of HDD with diferent operating systems, example:

1 partition i5/os
2 partition AIX

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: I'm missing the programming related question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq, you should try http://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: I know newer versions of AIX and i5/OS support PC-style partitions. I'm not sure which boot manager you can/should use or how to set it up however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Abel said, this should be on Server Fault. Since it'll probably just get moved. I'll still answer here.

Yes, you can do that though I am not sure exactly how. Your best bet is to contact your business partner for costs and how to proceed. Another resource would be [MIDRANGE-L at midrange.com](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/midrange-l), I am pretty sure there are others that have done this.